# Wireless at 200 dBm?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kubuntu

So my desktop computer comes with a built-in wireless adapter part of the motherboard and now I installed an Alpha wi-fi adapter to play around with.

The built in wifi on wlan0 says it's running at 200 dBm power! Which I know it's impossible otherwise I may be able to get the wireless signals of the whole country ;-)

and the other one maxes out at 20 dBm, Ive tried to do the following to increase the alpha power to 30 doing the following:

sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iw reg set BO
sudo iwconfig wlan1 txpower 30
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up

but I can't bring it higher than 20 even though theoretically I know it can go up to 30.

My two questions are,

Does anyone know why wlan0 shows at 200 dBm? (Which is clearly wrong!)

And why can't I bring wlan1 (the Alpha device) higher than 20?

Thank you!

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

Answer (score 0):

The 200dBm thing is probably a 23dBm card with a buggy driver accidentally reporting mW instead of dBm.

For the card you think should be capable of 30dBm but seems limited to 20dBm, it could be regional regulatory restrictions it's seeing from beacons of nearby APs, or it could be a default value it uses while unassociated. It might jump to its full potential when associated to an AP that says 30dBm operation is legal in its beacon information elements. It would be helpful if you posed the exact model of the card.